# Kendo Grid UI: Enable custom text copy with multiple row select feature

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a kendo grid where the multiple row selection is enabled. With multiple selection functionality, when users try to copy custom text like any value from the column, it enables multiple select features thus users cannot copy custom text.

Below is the sample:

https://dojo.telerik.com/@erpuneet507/ivAfoFup

The issue is, in the above example you can select text from a single cell/ or any partial text from the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple selection enabled, then your app has to handle the copy text to clipboard. In doing so, you'll need the `clipboard.js` library and add a Kendo ContextMenu. Handle the copy text in the ContextMenu `select` event. Copy Text should pop up on right click.

Try the code below in the Telerik DOJO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.7.1/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<ul id="context-menu">
  <li id="copyText">Copy Text</li>
</ul>
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      selectable: "multiple row",
      allowCopy: true,
      columns: [
          { field: "productName" }, 
          { field: "category" }
      ],
      dataSource: [
          { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
          { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
          { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
          { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
      ]
  });
  
  $("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
      target: "#grid",
      filter: "td",
      select: function (e) {
          var cell = e.target;
          var row = $(cell).parent()[0];
          var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
          var itemId = e.item.id;

          var cellText = cell.innerText;

          if (itemId === 'copyText') {
              new Clipboard('#copyText', {
                  text: function (trigger) {
                      return cellText;
                  }
              });
          };
      }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a revised version of the above. You'll no longer need the `clipboard.js`. This will show/pop up the text (e.g. coffee) when you right click so that you can copy the 'ffee'.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<ul id="context-menu">
  <li id="copyText">
    <input id="valueText"></input>
    <span id="closeValueText" class="k-icon k-i-close"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      selectable: "multiple row",
      allowCopy: true,
      columns: [
          { field: "productName" }, 
          { field: "category" }
      ],
      dataSource: [
          { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
          { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
          { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
          { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
      ]
  });
  
  var closeContextMenu = false;

  var contextMenu = $("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
      target: "#grid",
      filter: "td",
      close: function(e) {
          if (!closeContextMenu) {
              e.preventDefault();
          }  
      },
      open: function(e) {
          var cell = e.target;
          var row = $(cell).parent()[0];
          var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
          var itemId = e.item.id;

          var cellText = cell.innerText;
          
          $(e.item).find("#valueText").val(cellText);

          closeContextMenu = false;
      }
  }).data("kendoContextMenu");

  $("#closeValueText").on("click", function(e) {
      closeContextMenu = true;
      contextMenu.close();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not what I needed. I want to copy only a part of the text from the first column let's say 'ffee' from coffee, I can do that.

Comment: Like I said: "If you have multiple selection enabled, then your app has to handle the copy text to clipboard." So you'll need more code in the `select` event. You could show/pop up the text (e.g. coffee) when you right click so that you can copy the 'ffee'. That is the basic idea here.

Comment: Sure, Thanks jpllosa. I will try to work on this.

Comment: @PuneetGoel Apart from my second example, did you find another way to copy the text?

Comment: yes, I manually create this feature. https://dojo.telerik.com/@erpuneet507/ApehiTeq/4

Comment: @PuneetGoel I see you no longer have the `selectable: "multiple row",` Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yes, it's totally a manual thing I created. It works smoothly.